# Delphi - create Title/Proper/Mixed Case for Strings

Tags: delphi, text, case-sensitive

I have a list of approx 100,000 names I need to process.  Some are business names, some are people names.  Unfortunately, some are lower, some are upper, and some are mixed.  I am looking for a routine to convert them to proper case. (Sometimes called Mixed or Title case).  I realize I can just loop through the string and capitalize every character that starts a new word.  That would be an incredibly simplistic approach.  For businesses, short words should be lowercase (of, with, for, ...).  For last names, if it starts with Mc, the 3rd letter should be capitalized (McDermot, McDonald, etc).  Roman numerals should always be capitalized (John Smith II ), etc.

I have not been able to find any Delphi built in, or otherwise, routines.  Surely this is out there.  Where can I find this?

Thanks

Comment: I can not imagine a meaningful solution without extensive library, so this would become overly broad or searching for offline resources.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a tool recommendation site. The obvious solution is to implement this function yourself. It shouldn't be that difficult. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Andy_D - "Does Delphi have a function" is a valid question.  With all the edge cases, it is not a trivial issue, else I would have already written it myself.

Comment: This exercise can be a lot trickier than might first appear because there are no hard and fast rules about proper names.  Typically, automatic processing against a set of rules (which you'll need to devise yourself) will leave a residue of 10+% which are either wrong or require manual massaging.  A lot of factors require "policy" decisions: e.g. is SomeCo Inc the same entity as SomeCo Incorporated, which may depend on your purpose.  And, what rules to apply to a name like "E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company"?  We found 20+ valid variants of that one in our data.

Comment: Btw, the freeware Systools library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/?source=directory) contains a couple of functions, ExtractWord and WordCount which are very handy for snipping up name strings using arbitrary delimiters and re-assembling them into standardised formats.

Comment: @Andy_D is correct. From the [site help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: In case you do decide to write your own routine, be aware that there will always be exceptions.  For example, I spell my name "Dubois", but some spell it "DuBois".  Many times a computer has changed my name to "correct" the spelling, and it's always a little upsetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already said by others, making a fully automated routine for this is nearly impossible due to so many special variations. So leaving out the human interaction completely is almost impossible.

Now what you can do instead is to make this much easier for human to solve. How? Make a dictionary of all the name variations in Lowercase and present it to him.
Before presenting the names you can make sure that the first letter in any of the names is already capitalized.

Once all name correction has been made in dictionary you go and automatically replace all the names in original database.

Comment: The other variation of this is to assume that if the word/phrase is already mixed case, then it is probably right.  Maybe do some marginal checking....

Comment: I gues you could do that yes.